# How can I create a Spring web project when using manually imported jar files?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am starting to learn Spring framework. I have confusion that why should i use maven? Instead of i can add jar files manually. I have found spring examples on web and all of that used maven so pom.xml is there. But i have no idea why it required. And i have use an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) but whenever i tried to call url it shows error that " The requested resource is not available." So how spring works actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information

for small project for study purpose maven is not needed when you are going to do enterprise application that include 100s of jar file with multiple version and dependency in such cause maven can do significant role .

Maven primary goal is to provide developer

1.A comprehensive model for projects which is reusable, maintainable, and easier to comprehend.

2.plugins or tools that interact with this declarative model.

Maven project structure and contents are declared in an xml file, pom.xml referred as Project Object Model (POM), which is the fundamental unit of the entire Maven system. Refer to Maven POM section for more detail.

i think using maven is best practice.

in your project i think problem with web.xml

Comment: I have copied whole project from upper given link. So can you tell me where changes are required? @MiDhuN

Comment: no changes required download required jar .. and add jara or libraries to project build path .. maven also doing this process but it automated . i hope u using eclipse check how add external jar in eclipse java project

Comment: I have added all jar files but still i getting same error. @MiDhuN

Answer (score 0):

To do this manually, come up with a scope of what you want to achieve/learn so that you can find out which libraries you want to use. Otherwise, there are too many jars to deal with. Download the specific jar files and make sure they are available in the classpath of your project. That's all you need to create a project by manually importing jar files.

As far as maven goes, it will make your life easier as it handles all dependencies for you. When you use one component of spring, it can use 5 other jar files (which you will have to import manually if you don't use maven). In such case, you can tell maven which spring component you want to use and it will sort out the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Spring tool Suite built on eclipse, It allows to create various combinations of spring projects like spring + maven, spring + web, etc., It generates the project structure along with it also generates pom.xml file, which inturn downloads all libraries.

follow the below download link for spring tool suite.

https://spring.io/tools/sts

2. for elipse use plugin for spring tool suite. it works as same a above point explained